# Cannot keyframe anymore. All movement stopped and every keyframe is the same

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet, timeline

In the Dopesheet, I had an animation. Now for an unknown reason, the armature bones move but the object does not, LocRotScale wise. While I can perform the steps of moving my object in OBJECT mode, and inserting or replacing a keyframe, it is updating all the keyframes. As if there were no keyframes. I can't keyframe any rotational or positional motion. Armature keyframes are still moving, but all motion associated with the armature itself... it's lost. The keyframes are there, but they're all the same, and I cannot change them.

Here's a video of my screen.
https://vimeo.com/298955191

Comment: could you please share the file with only the armature? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: OK done. I left just a few other objects in there for scale   [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5485" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5485/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Dopesheet* tracks, you've disabled the speakers icons (*Do Channels Contribute to Result*), it mutes all the keyframes of the track, therefore you can't see the changes you've made, so it's going to be a bit messy in your scene now that you'll reactivate it

[image]

Comment: 1) IDK what Speakers have to do with anything? There may be some guide audio left in this file from before but it's not relevant to anything I'm doing now or the problem at hand. (Question for another place: why are there audio speakers in a LotRotScale track??)

2) The LocRotScale is Locked but you can unlock it and should get the same result. I was checking that.

Thanks

Comment: it's not for audio, it's to mute the keyframes

Comment: And that's the answer.   Holy crap.   Thank you.